# Silverlight unable to start debugging

Tags: silverlight

I'm trying to run a sivlerlight website in Windows 7 64-bit. I have VS 2008 SP1 and downloaded silverlight 3 SDK. It installed succesfully and everything, but I'm getting this error when I try to compile:

"unable to start debugging the silverlight managed debugging package isn't installed"

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need more than the SDK to debug silverlight, the [Silverlight Tools for Silverlight 3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=9442B0F2-7465-417A-88F3-5E7B5409E9DD&displaylang=en) which also includes the version of the runtime that is debuggable.

You may also need to install the Silverlight 4 developer runtime, since its quite likely you will run into a site the requires silverlight 4 but installing the standard 4 runtime will put you at square one.

This is the link to the silverlight 4 dev runtime:-

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188039

Comment: Sounds good. Do I have to uninstall anything before installing these two?